# Backbone Form Validation on type

Tags: forms, validation, backbone.js

I was wondering if there is a clean way in backbone to validate forms as you type without using a plugin. The issue is that if you have say a user model with: name, surname, email...
You can validate the model as a whole but not each model attribute individually.

Example:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
validate: function(attrs) {
  if(!attrs.name) return "name not set"
}

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: { 'keyup input' : 'validateInput' },
  validateInput: return this.model.isValid()
 })
```

Comment: You can add whatever methods you'd like to your model.

Answer (score 1):

One generic method you can use is :

```
events: {
    'keyup input': 'validateFeild'
},
validateFeild: function (event) {
    var value = event.currentTarget.value;
    var validator = $(event.currentTarget).attr('validator');
    console.log(validator);
    // Utils.validate(value, validator); here you can manage the validation in a separate utility class
}
```

and in your html have something like that :

```
<input id="label" type="text" validator="required" />
```

[Here's the full example](http://jsfiddle.net/q9zxd/)